# Exchange Server CU Update

Tags: exchange-2016, exchange-2019

I am planning to migrate our current Exchange server 2016 CU19 (Hybrid Setup with MS365) to Exchange server 2019. Do I still need to install CU11 on the current exchange server 2016? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

No. Cumulative Updates are cumulative. Everything that was in CU11 is in CU19.

Comment: got it. do I need to update my Exchange 2016 CU to latest version before migrating to Exchange 2019?

Answer (score 0):

You need to update Exchange 2016 to the latest CU. This is required to upgrade the version.
You could refer to the guide in this link to upgrade hybrid 2016 to 2019:
[Exchange Server 2016 Cumulative Update - Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1156123/exchange-server-2016-cumulative-update-1.html?childToView=1157873#answer-1157873)

Comment: Hi ,
Just checking in to see how things are going on with this thread.
If the reply was helpful, You can mark helpful posts as the best answers so that other's with similar question can benefit from this thread as well.